# MongoDB resident memory spikes, mapped memory disappears

Tags: mongodb, memory

I'm trying to understand a MongoDB memory use pattern that I see in our [MMS](https://mms.10gen.com/) logs.

Normally, resident memory sits around 3GB, virtual memory is steady at 84GB, and mapped memory is about 41GB. Then in a series of peaks and troughs, usually for just a few minutes, mapped memory disappears completely, virtual memory drops to around 41GB, and resident memory 41GB or spikes to 84GB. In one recent episode, however, the peaks and troughs lasted 3.5 hours.

[image: mongodb memory peaks and troughs] [image: mongodb memory peaks and troughs detail]

MongoDB appears to be running normally and other metrics such as opcounters and network are normal, but graphs suddenly changing dramatically when there was unlikely to be a significant load change makes me ... curious.

This is a standalone instance running MongoDB 1.8.3.

Typical memory usage, not during an episode (I only found the longer episode as it was ending):

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32176      31931        245          0        628      29449
-/+ buffers/cache:       1854      30322
Swap:         1983          0       1983
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MMS gets memory statistics from the operating system by reading /proc/$PID/stat.  The fluctuations in virtual and resident memory are reporting errors, and can safely be ignored.

(if you hover over the spikes, you'll notice that they occur at times when 1 or 2 of the 3 stats- virtual memory, mapped memory, or resident memory - is missing...)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any idea what might have caused the extended reporting errors?

Comment: If I had to venture a guess, it would be that MMS started polling data at a rate that overlapped/ was in sync with journal flushes, affecting one or more of the memory statistics.  The parsing of individual stats is flawed, and the fluctuations appear to be linked to points on the MMS graph when one or more of the 3 stats is not reported. I would have to do more detailed investigation to determine the exact cause of the errors.